# What should I do for deprecated npm modules for express generator?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, express-generator

```
express website

npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer
```

(I am just following a tutorial.)
Will installing `jstransformer` and `pug` be not enough? Am I supposed to edit code of `express`?
Can I use something like this for production?

I don't understand how deprecation work and what I can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

Express Generator just sets up some boiler plate code for you. You are not committed to any of modules that it uses. Since you are following along in a tutorial, I would recommend you not do anything about the deprecated packages. you may run into some problems otherwise following along with your tutorial...and get frustrated because you are using a different setup from the author.

Going forward, and for these particular packages, you will want to remove the deprecated packages first, example: npm uninstall jade
Then install the correct one, npm install pug --save

Answer (score 0):

They use `express myapp --view=pug` in their tutorial [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html). This way you'll end up with up-to-date software packages.

Comment: this is not true at least for express 4.0.0 as installed from the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS repos. Even with `--view=pug` it will require `jade` , not `pug` and install vulnerabilities via `constantinople`.